# again about C++ SFINAE in enable_if_t

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'm trying to figure out why SFINAE doesn't work with a direct template argument initialization?

It works in this form, when I declare another template parameter, here:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool B, class T = void>
class enable_if {};

template <class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {    typedef T type; };

template <bool B, class T>
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;

template< typename T >
struct Y {

public:
    template< typename U = T >
    enable_if_t<true, U>
    foo() {
        return 111;
    }

    template< typename U = T >
    enable_if_t<false, U>
    foo() {
        return 222;
    }
};

int main() {
    Y< double > y;
    std::cout << y.foo() << std::endl;
}
```

(prints out 111)

but if I refactor to this syntax, the compiler gives an error:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool B, class T = void>
class enable_if {};

template <class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {
    typedef T type;
};

template <bool B, class T>
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;

template< typename T >
struct Y {    
    template< typename U = enable_if_t<true, T> >
    U
    foo() {
        return 11;
    }

    template< typename U = enable_if_t<false, T> >
    U
    foo() {
        return 12;
    }
};

int main() {
    Y< double > y;
    std::cout << y.foo() << std::endl;
}
```

"Class member cannot be redeclared" I assume the second instance formed invalid and should be excluded by SFINAE?

And why can't I declare foo()'s like this:

```
enable_if_t<true, T> foo() { return 11; } 
enable_if_t<false, T> foo() { return 12; }
```

based just on the class template's T parameter? 
the second enable_if_t should not be valid and the instance of foo() should be discarded, right?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you declare two class methods:

```
template<typename U> U foo();
```

You can't have two template class methods with the same signature and name just like you can't declare two non-template class methods with the same signature and name:

```
int bar();
```

and

```
int bar();
```

Your two template class methods have different template parameters defaults, but that is immaterial. Template parameter defaults are not considered to be a part of the signature. SFINAE does not come into play here. SFINAE is something that happens when template ***substitution*** occurs, the "S" part, not declaration.

Comment: but why then can't I declare simply: 

enable_if_t<true, T>
    foo() {
        return 11;
    }

    enable_if_t<false, T>
    foo() {
        return 12;
    }
based on class template's parameter? the second enable_if_t should not be valid and the instance of foo() should be discarded, right?

Comment: Because, again, SFINAE occurs when template substitution is performed. You have to have valid template declarations before you can use the template to substitute something. At that point, Substitution Failure Is Not An Error. But you have to have a valid template declaration first, before you can get down to the business of attempting to substitute something. And you can't declare two class methods with the same signature and name. The End.

Comment: I don't get the difference.. So the "absent" return type is invalid declaration and means compiler error, right? But once I get the valid declarations, why the "template< typename U = T > enable_if_t<true, U>  foo()" goes to the different "Substitution" stage? In other words, how do you differentiate? How exactly can you tell (from the syntax point of view) that you should write another template parameter "U" and declare the return type through enable_if<U> and that would work as a substitution... I.e. I'm just trying to figure out the mental model of how to write such code "from the scratch"